# Xcode Pre-actions run python script environment variables not setting ${PROJECT_DIR} properly

Tags: python, xcode

I am attempting to run a python script from Xcode in the Build Pre-actions:

[image: screenshot]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import shutil
import os

app_name = 'name'

def skinfunction(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir):
    for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
        print(str(files))
        dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
            os.mkdir(dst_dir)
        for file_ in files:
            src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
            dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
            if os.path.exists(dst_file):
                os.remove(dst_file)
            shutil.copy(src_file, dst_dir)
root_src_dir = '${PROJECT_DIR}/skins/'+str(app_name)+'/authorize_bg.imageset'
root_dst_dir = '${PROJECT_DIR}/iDetail/Images.xcassets/authorize_bg.imageset'
skinfunction(root_src_dir,root_dst_dir);
```

Nearing the end of the script I am trying to get the PROJECT_DIR Xcode environment variable, but it is just not working properly. Either the value is invalid or my formatting is off.

If I hard code the PROJECT_DIR value (the full url to where the project resides) and the script runs successfully.

Am I missing something in trying to get the environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, instead of trying to get the environment variable directly by using ${PROJECT_DIR} you need to call os.getenv() function. I was able to get the environment variable by calling:

```
proj_dir = os.getenv('PROJECT_DIR')
```

Comment: not sure about python but in case anyone is using /bin/sh you can just use `$PROJECT_DIR`, pretty handy!